# How do you get an iterator to a row of a boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T>?

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

I'm working on matrix multiplication, and I would like an iterator over a single row of a boost matrix? Can this be done?

Currently, I have to get an iterator and advance it. It seems like too much CPU work / non-optimized...

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T> aMatrix(2048, 4096);
typename boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T>::iterator it;
it = aMatrix.data().begin();
offset = row * aMatrix.size2();
advance(it, offset);
```

Comment: Forgo iterators and use the array like operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eureka! [Matrix proxies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_proxy.htm)...

```
boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_row<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<T> > aRow(aMatrix, row);
```